# Plupload internal version is wrong? File is called 2.3.9, but version in the file is 2.3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

We have a security vulnerability issue where plupload 2.3.6 is cited as vulnerable.
And the easy fix is to download 2.3.9 which we did from here:
https://www.plupload.com/download/

And the zip file is called 2.3.9, but version number within the plupload.min.js the file is 2.3.6.
Now, I've just seen that the version inside the plupload.full.min.js is 2.3.9!
And that plupload.dev.js contains 2.3.6!

Any tips on the best way forward - to ensure we're not using a vulnerable version?

[image: Plupload file mismatch?]

Answer (score 1):

they have released version 3.1.5 (https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/archive/v3.1.5.zip) which in the minimized version js file has

> Plupload - multi-runtime File Uploader * v3.1.2, probably best to try that version, I wonder if they just forgot to update the js file notes

I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I think that is the way we will have to go. They claim that 3.x.x contains a big re-write of the code and it's much better. But they also state that the most stable is 2.3.9 - which is exactly why we went that way first. But, given the version number mess - and the lack of confidence that comes with that - I think testing their new version (3.1.5) is the only sensible way forward.

Comment: yer think your best bet is to simply go for the newer version, this is one of the problems of npm packages and been at the mercy of someone else code base, hopefully they tested the re-write and you won't have any issues